# The update information is outdated (notification icon)

Tags: apt, 12.10, updates

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 server

I'm getting this icon in the notification bar over the last days, even though Software Center is running updates properly and I have no new updates available.

I have run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and still have this problem.
The output after running `sudo apt-get update` is:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.2)/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.2)/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you use 12.10 and not 14.10? 12.10 is end-of-life.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Unity dash (or other menu system) and open "Software Sources" sometimes also called "Software & Updates". Then what you need to do is go to the "Other Software" tab, and uncheck the option listing a cdrom. Then click apply, and update again and that should fix it

Comment: This works for me

1.Open software and updates

2.Under Ubuntu software/Installable from CD-ROM/DVD

3.Untick CDrom with Ubuntu 14.10 'Utopic Unicorn'


Thanks

Comment: Sorry I have changed it to Ubuntu server 14.10

Comment: If this helped, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. We will both gain reputation.